# How does the build widget get executed in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

It is a really beginner question but have to ask for my learning satisfaction

Code snippet from flutter / dart app :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("MY FIRST APPLication"),
      ),        
    ),
  );
}
```

I understand what this code does but what I am not understanding what  'home' and 'appBar' ? Is home a variable defined inside MaterialApp or a widget.

What does ':' signifies? does it means we are creating a new widget -  in this case Scaffold - and storing it in home or home is referencing to Scaffold ?

Can someone clarify this ?

(I tried google)
Thanks,

Comment: `home`, `appBar`, and `title` are all named parameters of the `MaterialApp`, `Scaffold`, and `AppBar` object constructors, respectively. It sounds as though you are trying to learn Flutter before you have learned Dart, so I suggest that you look up a [tutorial on understanding Dart code](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour) and mess around on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am going to learn dart first.

Answer (score 0):

'home' and 'appBar' are properties of widget in flutter.
You can also take a look https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html, https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html.